# Removing background from text

Tags: plotting, labeling, version-12

I have the following plot
[image]

I'd like to remove the edges of what look like boxes around the text with T's. For example, the $5T_2$ label has a hard edge around it which cuts into the lines. Is there a way to remove this background?

I used the following for the data

```
data1 = {
   n1[[;; , 3 ;; 4]],
   n2[[;; , 3 ;; 4]],
   n4[[;; , 3 ;; 4]],
   n8[[;; , 3 ;; 4]],
   n16[[;; , 3 ;; 4]],
   n32[[;; , 3 ;; 4]],
   Callout[n64[[;; , 3 ;; 4]], "64", After, FrameMargins -> None, 
    LeaderSize -> 5],
   Callout[n128[[;; , 3 ;; 4]], "128", After, FrameMargins -> None, 
    LeaderSize -> 5],
   Callout[ntheory[[;; , 3 ;; 4]], "\[Infinity]", After, 
    FrameMargins -> None, LeaderSize -> 5]
   };
places1 = Placed[
   {"1", "2", "4", "8", "16", "32"},
   {{21.5, 0.32}, {12.5, 1.1}, {31, 3.84}, {31, 14.66}, {31, 
     37.5}, {31, 75}}
   ];
data2 = {
   r1[[;; , 3 ;; 4]],
   r2[[;; , 3 ;; 4]],
   r3[[;; , 3 ;; 4]],
   r4[[;; , 3 ;; 4]],
   r5[[;; , 3 ;; 4]],
   r6[[;; , 3 ;; 4]],
   r7[[;; , 3 ;; 4]],
   r8[[;; , 3 ;; 4]],
   r9[[;; , 3 ;; 4]],
   r10[[;; , 3 ;; 4]]
   };
places2 = 
  Placed[{Style["1\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(T\), \(2\)]\)", 
     Background -> {None, Opacity[0]}], 
    Style["2\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(T\), \(2\)]\)", 
     Background -> Lighter[Gray, 1]], 
    "3\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(T\), \(2\)]\)", 
    "4\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(T\), \(2\)]\)", 
    "1\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(T\), \(1\)]\)", 
    "5\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(T\), \(2\)]\)", 
    "6\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(T\), \(2\)]\)", 
    "7\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(T\), \(2\)]\)", 
    "8\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(T\), \(2\)]\)", 
    "9\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(T\), \(2\)]\)"},
   {{3, 1.5}, {5.8, 5}, {9, 12}, {12, 20}, {14, 25}, {16, 32}, {19, 
     45}, {22, 60}, {25, 90}, {28, 100}}
   ];
```

And to plot

```
img = Show[
  ListLinePlot[
   data1,
   ScalingFunctions -> "Log",
   PlotRange -> {{0, 30}, {0, 200}},
   Frame -> True,
   FrameTicks -> Automatic, 
   FrameLabel -> {Style["T", 14], 
     Style["(E+1/3)\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(n\), \(2\)]\)", 14]},
   PlotLabels -> places1
   ],
  ListLinePlot[
   data2,
   ScalingFunctions -> "Log",
   PlotStyle -> Dashed,
   PlotRange -> {{0, 30}, {0, 200}},
   PlotLabels -> places2
   ],
  Graphics[{White, Rectangle[Scaled[{1, 0}], ImageScaled[{1, 1}]]}],
  ListLinePlot[
   data1,
   ScalingFunctions -> "Log",
   PlotRange -> {{0, 30}, {0, 200}},
   PlotStyle -> Opacity[0],
   PlotLabels -> places1
   ],
  ImageSize -> Large
  ]
```

I can also provide the data if needed, but it's kind of long. Let me know if I need to post that as well.

Here is the data which was used for the plots.

```
{{0, 1, 6.1559, 0.268762, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 21.2234, 0.316673, 2, 0}, {0, 
  2, 4.29788, 0.671316, 1, 0}, {1, 2, 12.3117, 1.07505, 2, 0}, {0, 4, 
  3.33506, 0.972728, 1, 0}, {1, 4, 8.59587, 2.68529, 2, 0}, {2, 4, 
  14.3822, 3.59775, 3, 0}, {3, 4, 103.51, 5.12115, 9, 0}, {0, 8, 
  3.15531, 1.12982, 1, 0}, {1, 8, 6.67039, 3.89115, 2, 0}, {2, 8, 
  10.7852, 7.10209, 3, 0}, {3, 8, 17.1918, 10.7412, 4, 0}, {4, 8, 
  22.6351, 12.7895, 1, 1}, {5, 8, 28.7645, 14.391, 6, 0}, {6, 8, 
  49.2471, 17.2008, 8, 0}, {7, 8, 207.019, 20.4846, 18, 0}, {0, 16, 
  3.10751, 1.17763, 1, 0}, {1, 16, 6.31083, 4.51953, 2, 0}, {2, 16, 
  9.69797, 9.52761, 3, 0}, {3, 16, 13.3399, 15.5631, 4, 0}, {4, 16, 
  16.0614, 20.0555, 1, 1}, {5, 16, 17.291, 22.0215, 5, 0}, {6, 16, 
  21.5697, 28.4074, 6, 0}, {7, 16, 34.3835, 42.9646, 8, 0}, {8, 16, 
  45.2694, 51.1576, 2, 1}, {9, 16, 73.4464, 63.2197, 14, 0}, {10, 16, 
  146.495, 74.4367, 21, 0}, {11, 16, 414.038, 81.9384, 36, 0}, {0, 32,
   3.09517, 1.1901, 1, 0}, {1, 32, 6.21485, 4.71025, 2, 0}, {2, 32, 
  9.38272, 10.4148, 3, 0}, {3, 32, 12.6216, 18.078, 4, 0}, {4, 32, 
  14.5034, 23.2028, 1, 1}, {5, 32, 19.3944, 38.1056, 6, 0}, {6, 32, 
  22.9672, 49.8306, 7, 0}, {7, 32, 26.6821, 62.2602, 8, 0}, {8, 32, 
  32.123, 80.2231, 2, 1}, {9, 32, 34.5814, 88.0839, 10, 0}, {10, 32, 
  43.1396, 113.63, 12, 0}, {11, 32, 47.6313, 125.776, 13, 0}, {12, 32,
   71.2611, 176.253, 17, 0}, {13, 32, 90.5376, 204.629, 4, 1}, {14, 
  32, 292.991, 297.747, 42, 0}, {15, 32, 828.078, 327.754, 72, 0}, {0,
   64, 3.09215, 1.19332, 1, 0}, {1, 64, 6.19048, 4.7606, 2, 0}, {2, 
  64, 9.29984, 10.6613, 3, 0}, {3, 64, 12.4299, 18.8417, 4, 0}, {4, 
  64, 14.1178, 24.1366, 1, 1}, {5, 64, 15.5828, 29.2084, 5, 0}, {6, 
  64, 18.7656, 41.66, 6, 0}, {7, 64, 21.9839, 56.0735, 7, 0}, {8, 64, 
  25.2452, 72.3225, 8, 0}, {9, 64, 28.5489, 90.2278, 9, 0}, {10, 64, 
  31.906, 109.665, 10, 0}, {11, 64, 45.4461, 196.072, 3, 1}, {12, 64, 
  69.1626, 352.334, 20, 0}, {13, 64, 95.2646, 503.116, 26, 0}, {14, 
  64, 152.377, 737.595, 36, 0}, {15, 64, 215.82, 894.86, 46, 0}, {16, 
  64, 585.985, 1190.99, 84, 0}, {17, 64, 1656.15, 1311.01, 144, 
  0}, {0, 128, 3.09119, 1.19396, 1, 0}, {1, 128, 6.18433, 4.77331, 2, 
  0}, {2, 128, 9.28031, 10.728, 3, 0}, {3, 128, 12.3809, 19.0422, 4, 
  0}, {4, 128, 14.0225, 24.3839, 1, 1}, {5, 128, 15.4878, 29.6946, 5, 
  0}, {6, 128, 18.6017, 42.6541, 6, 0}, {7, 128, 21.7263, 57.8967, 7, 
  0}, {8, 128, 24.861, 75.3736, 8, 0}, {9, 128, 28.0055, 95.0272, 9, 
  0}, {10, 128, 31.1663, 116.839, 10, 0}, {11, 128, 40.7386, 194.506, 
  13, 0}, {12, 128, 47.2154, 255.886, 15, 0}, {13, 128, 57.1007, 
  360.945, 18, 0}, {14, 128, 60.4418, 399.07, 19, 0}, {15, 128, 
  77.577, 609.68, 24, 0}, {16, 128, 90.8961, 784.34, 6, 1}, {17, 128, 
  102.952, 945.587, 31, 0}, {18, 128, 118.272, 1149.82, 35, 0}, {19, 
  128, 159.424, 1667.05, 45, 0}, {20, 128, 431.637, 3579.43, 92, 
  0}, {-1., \[Infinity], 3.09114, 1.19439, 1., 0.}, {-1., \[Infinity],
   6.18228, 4.77757, 2., 0.}, {-1., \[Infinity], 9.27342, 10.7495, 3.,
   0.}, {-1., \[Infinity], 12.3646, 19.1103, 4., 
  0.}, {-1., \[Infinity], 13.9904, 24.4666, 1., 
  1.}, {-1., \[Infinity], 15.4557, 29.8598, 5., 
  0.}, {-1., \[Infinity], 18.5468, 42.9982, 6., 
  0.}, {-1., \[Infinity], 21.638, 58.5253, 7., 0.}, {-1., \[Infinity],
   24.7291, 76.4412, 8., 0.}, {-1., \[Infinity], 27.8203, 96.7459, 9.,
   0.}, {-1., \[Infinity], 27.9809, 97.8663, 2., 
  1.}, {-1., \[Infinity], 30.9114, 119.439, 10., 
  0.}, {-1., \[Infinity], 34.0025, 144.522, 11., 
  0.}, {-1., \[Infinity], 37.0937, 171.993, 12., 
  0.}, {-1., \[Infinity], 40.1848, 201.853, 13., 
  0.}, {-1., \[Infinity], 41.9713, 220.199, 3., 
  1.}, {-1., \[Infinity], 43.276, 234.101, 14., 
  0.}, {-1., \[Infinity], 46.3671, 268.739, 15., 
  0.}, {-1., \[Infinity], 49.4582, 305.765, 16., 
  0.}, {-1., \[Infinity], 52.5494, 345.18, 17., 
  0.}, {-1., \[Infinity], 55.6405, 386.984, 18., 
  0.}, {-1., \[Infinity], 55.9618, 391.465, 4., 
  1.}, {-1., \[Infinity], 58.7317, 431.176, 19., 
  0.}, {-1., \[Infinity], 61.8228, 477.757, 20., 
  0.}, {-1., \[Infinity], 64.914, 526.728, 21., 
  0.}, {-1., \[Infinity], 68.0051, 578.087, 22., 
  0.}, {-1., \[Infinity], 69.9522, 611.664, 5., 
  1.}, {-1., \[Infinity], 71.0962, 631.834, 23., 
  0.}, {-1., \[Infinity], 74.1874, 687.971, 24., 
  0.}, {-1., \[Infinity], 77.2785, 746.496, 25., 
  0.}, {-1., \[Infinity], 80.3697, 807.41, 26., 
  0.}, {-1., \[Infinity], 83.4608, 870.713, 27., 
  0.}, {-1., \[Infinity], 83.9427, 880.797, 6., 
  1.}, {-1., \[Infinity], 86.5519, 936.405, 28., 
  0.}, {-1., \[Infinity], 89.6431, 1004.49, 29., 
  0.}, {-1., \[Infinity], 92.7342, 1074.95, 30., 
  0.}, {-1., \[Infinity], 95.8254, 1147.81, 31., 
  0.}, {-1., \[Infinity], 97.9331, 1198.86, 7., 
  1.}, {-1., \[Infinity], 98.9165, 1223.06, 32., 
  0.}, {-1., \[Infinity], 102.008, 1300.69, 33., 
  0.}, {-1., \[Infinity], 105.099, 1380.72, 34., 
  0.}, {-1., \[Infinity], 108.19, 1463.13, 35., 
  0.}, {-1., \[Infinity], 111.281, 1547.93, 36., 
  0.}, {-1., \[Infinity], 111.924, 1565.86, 8., 
  1.}, {-1., \[Infinity], 114.372, 1635.13, 37., 
  0.}, {-1., \[Infinity], 117.463, 1724.7, 38., 
  0.}, {-1., \[Infinity], 120.554, 1816.67, 39., 
  0.}, {-1., \[Infinity], 123.646, 1911.03, 40., 
  0.}, {-1., \[Infinity], 125.914, 1981.79, 9., 
  1.}, {-1., \[Infinity], 126.737, 2007.78, 41., 
  0.}, {-1., \[Infinity], 129.828, 2106.91, 42., 
  0.}, {-1., \[Infinity], 132.919, 2208.43, 43., 
  0.}, {-1., \[Infinity], 136.01, 2312.35, 44., 
  0.}, {-1., \[Infinity], 139.101, 2418.65, 45., 
  0.}, {-1., \[Infinity], 139.904, 2446.66, 10., 
  1.}, {-1., \[Infinity], 142.192, 2527.34, 46., 
  0.}, {-1., \[Infinity], 145.284, 2638.42, 47., 
  0.}, {-1., \[Infinity], 148.375, 2751.88, 48., 
  0.}, {-1., \[Infinity], 151.466, 2867.74, 49., 
  0.}, {-1., \[Infinity], 154.557, 2985.98, 50., 0.}}
```

Hopefully adding this data will let you run the code. Sorry that it just had to be pasted in and not generated with Mathematica code.

Comment: Please add the code for your plot to your question. Otherwise we can't really help :)

Comment: I've added the code used to generate the plot.

Comment: Your code post is incomplete. It can't be run. Please give code needed to generate `data`. It doesn't need to be the full data set.

Comment: The data is actually generated from some C code, so I've given the data above.

Answer (score 2):

I worked with some contrived data and came up with this. I believe the general approach will work with your actual data even some of details need to changed.

Contrived data

```
data1 = Table[x^1.35 + 50, {x, 0, 33}];
data2 = Table[x^1.35, {x, 0, 33}]; 
places1 =
  Placed[
   {"1", "2", "4", "8", "16", "32"}, 
   Table[{x, Log[x^1.35 + 50]} // N, {x, Subdivide[2, 28, 5]}]];
places2 =
  Placed[
    {"1\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(T\), \(2\)]\)", 
     Style["2\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(T\), \(2\)]\)", Background -> Lighter[Gray, .6]], 
     "3\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(T\), \(2\)]\)", 
     "4\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(T\), \(2\)]\)", 
     "1\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(T\), \(1\)]\)", 
     "5\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(T\), \(2\)]\)", 
     "6\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(T\), \(2\)]\)", 
     "7\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(T\), \(2\)]\)", 
     "8\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(T\), \(2\)]\)", 
     "9\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(T\), \(2\)]\)"}, 
    N[{#[[1]], Log @ #[[2]]}] & /@ 
     {{3, 1.5}, {5.8, 5}, {9, 12}, {12, 20}, {14, 25}, {16, 32}, 
      {19, 45}, {22, 60}, {25, 90}, {28, 100}}];
```

The important thing to notice in the above is that because the plot data is going to log scaled, the y-components of label coordinates also have to be log scaled.

Given the properly scaled placements, the plotting can be done with the fairly  simple code that follows:

```
Show[
  ListLinePlot[data1,
    ScalingFunctions -> "Log",
    PlotRange -> {{0, 30}, {0, 200}},
    Frame -> True,
    FrameTicks -> Automatic, 
    FrameLabel -> 
      {Style["T", 14], Style["(E+1/3)\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(n\), \(2\)]\)", 14]},
    PlotLabels -> places1],
  ListLinePlot[data2,
    ScalingFunctions -> "Log",
    PlotStyle -> Dashed,
    PlotRange -> {{0, 30}, {0, 200}},
    PlotLabels -> places2],
 ImageSize -> Large]
```

[[image: plot[1]]

Note that none of labels, except for $2T_2$, has a background

Comment: The simplest way to achieve the same effect is to use option `Background->Transparent` inside the `Callout`